# Any ubuntu version above 14.04 crashes on powerbook g4

Tags: system-installation, lubuntu, crash, ubuntu-mate, powerpc

I have a PowerBook g4 with a 6gb hard drive 1gb of ram 1.3Ghz processor and a super drive. I tried installing lubuntu 16.04 and when the install screen was opened it would crash at one point seemingly randomly. So I tried to install xubuntu 9.04 and it worked. I tried installing ubuntu mate 16.04 and it crashed as well. I have been installing them from a USB stick because the super drive is dead. I really want to use this laptop with a moderately new version of ubuntu but It doesn't work. Does anyone have any idea why this happens.

Edit : The super drive now works so should I try to install it from a DVD-R?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94316/discussion-on-question-by-caleb-keatts-any-ubuntu-version-above-14-04-crashes-on).